# take picture from webcam c#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, directshow

I'm streaming video to my Window Form with DirectShowLib. I also want to save image when i press button "Save" for example. How to get picture from webcam with DirectShowLib methods or with WIN32 API methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectShow.NET Samples are there: http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/ The following sample demoes the requested function:

> Samples\VMR9\vMR9Snapper ------------------------ 
>   This sample shows how to capture bitmaps from VMR9.

Having it working with other renderer might require small code modifications.

The question also discussed a multitude of times at MSDN Forums, and on CodeProject, e.g. [how to save bmp file from IVMRWindowlessControl9->GetCurrentImage()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/e41d1837-866d-4372-8165-e68217573cb5/).